# Limit Azure staging application to selected IPs

Tags: azure, ip, azure-web-roles, staging

I'm testing an application in the staging slot within a given web role. I don't want the staging application to be accessible to the public and I was wondering if there was anything I could add to the .cscfg file to lock down the application to just a set of known IPs? I had a look around the portal but couldn't see any way to restrict IPs there.

Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enable the built in IIS IP and Domain Restrictions and then provide a list of IPs in your web.config (which sadly will mean a redeploy if you have to modify them).  Here is a link to a blog post where someone did this: http://blog.liamcavanagh.com/2011/10/how-to-block-ip-addresses-in-windows-azure/

Comment: Thanks Mike. The only problem here is that it will prevent me from being able to do a VIP swap when moving staging to production. It seems like the only option here is to write something into the code.

Comment: One option would be to have a startup task that reads your allowable IPs from a BLOB, database, table, service config, etc. and use AppCmd to configure the IIS module.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea! We're already using a startup task to register a DLL so maybe we can adapt this to set the allowable IPs.

Answer (score 0):

I never heard of it.

In your global.asax:

```
        protected void Session_Start()
        {
            if (Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"]!= "ÿour ip address here")
            {
                 Response.StatusCode = 404;
            }
        }
```

Comment: I was hoping to avoid hard-coding this but it may be my only option!

Comment: This is a "budget friendly" solution :)